# Separate tails of sequences in defining lim sup/inf

Tags: limsup-and-liminf

Why is on the following [link](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SupremumLimit.html) a limit superior of a sequence $$a_n=(-1)^n/n$$ defined separately for $n$ odd and even? Namely for $n$ odd its $A_n=1/(n+1)$ and for even its $A_n=1/n$. What does it even mean in this case when two sequences of supremums are defined?

Answer (score 0):

There is not two sequences of supremum defined. It is just that the value of $A_n = \sup_{k \ge n} a_k$ depends on $n$ odd or even. Then $\lim A_n =0$ and therefore $\limsup a_n =0$.

Comment: I don't understand, what is the point? $A_n = 0$ no matter if $n$ is even or odd.

Comment: My last comment was wrong. However the set of numbers considered contains strictly positive numbers. So its $\sup$ is strictly positive.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean.Maybe I don't understand the notation. What does this really mean? $A_n = \sup_{k \ge n} a_k$

Comment: It means $\sup \{a_n, a_{n+1}, \dots\}$.

Comment: Ah, sorry. So $A_n$ is a single sequence that is defined differently for $n$ odd or even, I was thinking it meant something else.